# How to update content type for a given item using lists.asmx web service in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2010

I am building a XML then I feed the xml to lists.asmx web services (updatelistitems) method. It works great. Now I need to add additional field. for example I have a column called "CT" and it's populated with Content Type name that I need to assign. so if CT has a value "Sales" then I need to assign "Sales" content type. How to assign content type using lists.asmx call with updatelistitems method?

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" ViewName="270C0508-A54F-4387-8AD0-49686D685EB2">
   <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
      <Field Name="ID">4</Field>
      <Field Name="Field_Name">Value</Field>
   </Method>
   <Method ID="2" Cmd="Update">
      <Field Name="ID" >6</Field>
      <Field Name="Field_Name">Value</Field>
   </Method>   
</Batch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line:

```
<Field Name='ContentType'>" + contentTypeName + "</Field>
```

Comment: <Field Name="ContentType">{ItemProperty:DocType}</Field>\
Added this but it did not help.